# Confusion regarding the coefficient of expansion

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Suppose the coefficient of linear expansion is $\alpha$, [and is, independent of T]. Then,
$$\alpha=\dfrac{dV}{VdT}$$
Upon integration, this yields : $V=V_{0}e^{\alpha(T-T_{0})}$. Using the maclaurin series for $e^x$, we get:

$$V=V_{0}(1+\alpha(T-T_{0}) +{\alpha^2(T-T_{0})}^2....)$$

However , Most textbooks simply write :
$$V=V_{0}(1+\alpha(T-T_{0}))$$

Which seems to be the result obtained if:

1. You neglect higher terms in the series. :i.e you assume small temperature difference, and thus this equation isnt *general*.
2. $\alpha$ is defined as $\dfrac{dV}{V_{0}dT}$.
3. $\alpha$ is defined as $\dfrac{\Delta{V}}{V_{0}\Delta T}$.

So what is it?

Comment: The textbook formula is simply the *standard definition* of the expansion coefficient, because in practical situations you want to know the change from some initial reference configuration (e.g. room temperature). There is nothing in the textbook formula that says $\alpha$ is independent of $T$, and for most real materials it is not.

Comment: The first equation is more exact.  The second is an approximation.  Note also that you have written this in terms of the coefficient of volume expansion.  The coefficient of linear expansion is 1/3 of this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking of the coefficient of *linear* expansion then you have already assumed linearity, which means you have already neglected higher order terms. You do this because you are talking of *empirical* physics, in which you recognise that your assumptions are an approximation to reality. Yes, there may well be higher terms, if you were able to do a more complete theoretical treatment, and you certainly don't expect perfect linearity, but you do expect linearity to be a decent approximation for a range of temperatures. You absolutely do not expect a perfect solution to a simplistic differential equation.

Comment: *"coefficient of **linear** expansion"* doesn't imply linearity. The *linear* in that phrase signifies that the expansion is only along one dimension. You could also have its counterparts, bamely, coefficient of areal expansion and coefficient of volume expansion. So using the linear word to imply linearity is a false argument.

Comment: @FakeMod. Linearity means what it says. This is a well defined term in both mathematics and physics. It does not mean one dimensional, but that a linear approximation is to be used.

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't know the word *"linear"* was used in that context. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis suppose i replace $\alpha$ with say, $\gamma$. The issue at hand will be the exact same, what will be your explanation in that case?

Comment: @satan29, why would replacing $\alpha$ with $\gamma$ make any difference, either to the issue or my answer?

Comment: because...$\gamma$ isnt called the coefficient of *linear* expansion? Or is it?

Comment: well it would be if you were to simply change $\alpha$ to $\gamma$